# Problems with using the jQuery watermark and rails validations

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Ok so i have a text field that uses this [jQuery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/) watermark plugin which is really easy to implement. The problem comes into play when i need to validate this field with a rails validation. For example..

```
def validate 
  errors.add(:price, "should be at least $0.01") if price < 0.01 
end
```

I am using the plugin like this

```
 $("#request_price").Watermark("Not at this time");
```

The params are coming in like this

```
"price"=>"Not at this time",
```

I need to make sure if the user enters a price it is over 1 cent and if they leave the field blank that nothing goes in the db. But how do i stop the params from coming in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you really wanted to control this in the views, you could use a plugin which honors placeholder text (standard in HTML5), versus this home-spun solution. [Here's such a plugin](http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/).

Then, you could bind an event to the form submit, and if the value is the placeholder value, set the value to `""`. Something like

```
$('form').submit(function(){
$(this).find('input').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder") ){
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
});
```